# Sports Collection Database

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am creating a sports collection database of different sports and i am confused of some sort on what tables and primary keys/foreign key combo to use the requirement is as follows:

Should be in a 3rd Normal Form or at least in 3NF.

Here is the Full Description on what I want to do:

1. Design a database for a sports collection of cards.
2. You only purchase cards with current market value( at the time of purchase) that are at least $100.00. Your collection about 1000 cards
3. You collect all kinds of sports cards, from football, basketball, hockey and etc
4. These cards you collect are produced by different vendors such as ?Topps, Upper Deck, Leaf and Panini.
5. The collection spans many years of collection, some cards even date back to early 1900s, but there are cards made even before this
6. The condition of your cards vary too and are grade according to the 10-point PSA grading standards. (Grading table)
7. Everytime you purchase a card, you must know the date of purchase, cost of purchase, the market value of that purchase, whom you purchased it from, sport, the individual on the cards, card number and etc.
8. After completion of purchase, you send the card out for grading about a week later, you want to be able to keep track on when the card was sent out for grading, status of the grading, graded assigned to the card , when it was return by the grading company and receipt of the returned card. for tax purposes, you also want to know the fee paid for the grading service (grade table)
9. you do buy and sell cards, so you also want to know how much you sold the card for for, when it was sold, to whom it was sold, shipping fee if applicable and any relevant data pertinent to sale transaction. You are free to include any additional data that you believe is important to the table.

Here is my current database so far... I feel like i am missing something and I did not follow the requirements properly

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a pretty good start. I have the following observations about your tables/structure:

**CardSellers**: should only store info about the CardSeller; the only values it should have are SellerID and SellerName

**Vendor**: should not have CardId

**Grade**: SellerID doesn't belong here

**Card**: looks good

**CardBuyers** should not have DateOfPurchase or CostOfCard or Shipping Fee; those three members belong in CardTransaction. In fact, "DateOfPurchase" should be "DateOfTransaction"

Also, since the Vendor table should only store Vendor data, and the Card table should only store card data, you also need a M2M (many-to-many) table to connect the two; this should have three members: ID (PK), CardId (FK), and VendorId (FK)

### UPDATE

Remember two things about table design:

```
(0) A table should only contain data about the object its named for and only references to other tables (via a FK - see below)
(1) DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself - IOW, don't store the same data in multiple places; instead, store a link to it, where needed, via FK (Foreign Key) fields referencing PK (Primary Key) fields).
```

As far as the actual design of the tables, this makes sense to me:

```
CARDS
-----
CardId (PK)
VendorId (FK)
CardFirstName
CardLastName
CardType
CardYear
MarketValue
Rarity
CollectionNumber    

COLLECTORS (Buyers and/or Sellers; no need to have separate tables for them)
---------
CollectorId (PK)
CollectorName
CollectorAddress    

TRANSACTIONS
------------
TransId (PK)
CardId (FK)
BuyerId (FK) <= CollectorId in the Collectors table
SellerId (FK) <= CollectorId in the Collectors table
TransactionDate
Price (if it may differ from CARDS.MarketValue)

GRADE
-----
GradeId (PK)
CardId (FK)
Points
AssignedGrade
Qualifiers
Status
CardFee
GradedDate
ReturnedDate

VENDORSLU ("LU" stands for "Lookup")
---------
VendorId (PK)
VendorName
CARDTYPESLU
-----------
CardTypeID (PK)
CardTypeDescription

RARITYLU
-----------
RarityID (PK)
RarityDescription
```

You may find there are other fields you need to add, too, but that should be close. You might even want additional lookup tables, such as for "Qualifiers" and "Status" in the GradeTable.

You might also want a SPORTSLU table, and then add a SportId FK to the CARDS table (where if SportId == 1, it's a football card, if it's 2, it's a basketball card, &c).

Note, though, that as prevalent and historically significant as Relational Databases are, there is another animal called "Non-SQL" databases (such as MongoDB) which are more free-form/loosey-goosey/I'm okay-you're okay/anarchistic, which allow you to have records, or "documents" that can omit or add whatever members it wants on the fly. Relational Databases can be compared to Classical music (Bach, Mozart, &c) whereas Non-SQL are more like Jazz (free-flowing, improvisational).

And BTW, why no mention of *Tiddlywinks*? Football, Baseball, etc., are fine, but no Tiddlywinks (or Bocci Ball, for that matter)**?!?**

Comment: lol i'm sorry ;_; tiddywinks was too good for my unstable database ;_;

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the relationship though?

Comment: since vendor should not have the CARDID, where would it be connected to then?

Comment: Grade: ReturnedDate and SellerID don't belong there ;; it says on number 8 that i have to have a return date when it was returned by the grading company

Comment: Since vendor should only store Vendor data, and Card should only contain card data, you also need a M2M (many-to-many) table that has three members: ID (PK), CardId (FK), and VendorId (FK)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the raison d'etre of ReturnedDate; it does belong in Grade after all, then, based on your description.

Comment: Yay ... now ... I'm a bit confused now though...what would the tables be then and their fields?  I know Card, Vendor, CardSeller, Grade, Card Buyer , CardSet(With the ID, CardID, and VendorID) .. could you list them instead base from my tables and fields? and based from the suggestion you made

Comment: also it did say i buy and sell the cards too so do i really have to put everything in the transaction table?

Comment: thank you! ;_; Tiddlywinks will be an olympic sports now with this

Comment: i got to say on the buy and sell question...shouldn't they have their separate transaction dates and purchases prices?  selling and buy?

Comment: Aren't they sold and bought at the same time? If I sell you a 1956 Willie Mays right now, the selling date for me would be the same as your buying date (or a 1938 Rupert Pupkin, the most famous TiddlyWinker of all time). You might want to add a "TransactionType" member to the Transactions table, though, with two types: SellerToBuyer and VendorToBuyer. In that case, the SellerId would either come from the Vendors table or the Sellers table. All of this is malleable, really - it depends on your specific needs and such. Programming is a matter of refactoring, after all.

Comment: basically i'm buying it from the vendor and i am selling to to someone else when i bought it from the vendor/manufacturer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96935/discussion-between-aldz24-and-b-clay-shannon).

Comment: wait ....if buyerid and sellerid are related to the collectors table do you want me to make a seperate table with the collectorsid, buyerid and sellerid in one seperate table? aren't they supposed to be different people?

Comment: No, they are the same thing with different names; BuyersId and SellersId in the Transactions table are the same thing as CollectorsId in the Collections table. Think of it as a collection of tables of Checkers players: there could be a PLAYERS table with a PlayerId and a GAMES table that recorded who played who, with a BlackPlayerId and a RedPlayerId, but all of them would be values from PLAYERS.PlayerId